# ASP.NET with ReportViewer, LocalProcessing, and DataSets

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, plsql, reportviewer

Language: C#
Tools: Visual Studio 2010
NET: .NET 4.0 and ASP.NET WebForms
ReportViewer v.10

I am a new web developer, usually a desktop application guy, and I don't have a mentor or guide on learning this stuff so I thought I would ask StackOverflow.

**Issue: ReportViewer has a long pause / delay before it starts rendering to screen. I am trying to ascertain if I understand the process stack.**

**I am retrieving a large DataSet, around 90,000 items in a single table, from Oracle SQL. The Query is built via a custom object and adding parameters.  I think it's a wrapper for simplifying ODBC connection or something. This maybe bottleneck number one.** You may ask, RagingCain, why don't you just look into it?  Fact of the matter is, there are several hundred thousand lines of code that neither I nor my team has written. The previous team was apparently paid per line / per hour and the entire project is spaghetti. I simply can't spend my very little time deep diving, unless, I can better pin point the hold up up front.

The query executes for about a total of  11700ms on the server side. The ReportView initial render is 300~500ms then another 5000ms loading the data. The oddity occurs that it takes 10~20 seconds between the finished query and initial rendering of the ReportViewer. I finally timed the before and after the creating of the DataSet retrieval and it takes anywhere from 11 to 12 seconds. Now, that 11 to 12 seconds also includes the time it takes to execute the query. That leaves a gap of 10 to 15 seconds I can't account for.

I at first thought it was ReportViewer acting weird with UpdatePanels/AJAX. During initial development, of course, I dealt with Asynchronous/TimeOuts exception occurring and OutOfMemory exceptions. I worked around all those issues and eliminated them as the possible causes. There are zero unhandled or handled exceptions occurring that could also be culprit and there is no JavaScript involved at all. I have isolated it down to executing query, assigning DataSet, setting ReportViewer datasource, binding, and refreshing. The big time gap occurs after query and before setting ReportViewer datasource.

A fact that leaves me puzzled was that I assumed DataSets "fill" with data, not transported in one large object like a file over the network. I was under the impression if the Query took 7 seconds, the DataSet took about the same time to be assigned. It appears though that the delay may roughly be the time it takes to send the DataSet to client (which is then used in LocalProcessing.)

Work Flow:
Client Initiates Query Event
C# BackEnd on WebServer tells PL/SQL server which procedure to execute
PL/SQL Server executes Procedure
C# BackEnd retrieves DataSet from SQL/Server
Sends Data from Web Server To Client
ReportViewer on Client Processes DataSet

Is my understanding correct?
Is this a data transfer I am seeing behind the scenes?
 What can I (high level) do to optimize the process?

Keep in mind LocalProcessing is being used on ReportViewer for Enabling HyperLinks which I am told is not available on RemoteProcessing.

ReportViewer Properties Set:
    ProcessingMode = LocalProcessing
    HyperLinks = Enabled
    AsynchRendering = True
    SizeReportToPageContent = True

Comment: How big is the generated page?

Comment: 43 rows, guessing approximately 1cm per row and 2.5cm for header.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean when you save the generated page to disk, how much space does it occupy? 1-5 Megs?

Comment: I don't know how one would calculate this.

Comment: Generate the report and then, in your browser, click on file->save. The saved file will give you a quick estimate of the page size.

Comment: This method, into a single archive file was 1.3 MB.  Total Memory differential immediately before DataSet and immediately after DataSet is about 105 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling [tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx)

> If tracing is enabled, when the page is requested, ASP.NET appends to the page a series of tables containing execution details about the page request.

The generated tables include detailed statistics on how much time is spent rendering the events of the page.

To see tracing with the trace viewer add this to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then access your application normally, and when you want to see the trace navigate to Trace.axd in the root of your application.

For example, if the URL for your application is http://localhost/SampleApplication, navigate to http://localhost/SampleApplication/trace.axd to view the trace information for that application.

Comment: Anyway to manually shift the tracing output location? It's embedded behind some of the controls and difficult to read.

Comment: I have the trace, researching how to trigger a trace update after query has run.